# Kiwi testing on iOS for Asynchronous with delegates

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ocunit

I am trying to work with kiwi testing for an asynchronous component.

I have read the **kiwi wiki notes** (http://www.kiwi-lib.info/mocks_and_stubs.html) and the one on  asynchronous, and the example they have had a block for the request.

Now, I have a class [SensisAPIDataFetcher](https://github.com/amleszk/sensis-api-iphone/blob/master/Classes/SensisAPIDataFetcher.m) which utilises **ASIHTTPRequest** and hence I need my spec file to implement the delegate created in **SensisAPIDataFetcher** but as the spec doesnt have a header file, how do i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I've posted an answer to your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616255/how-to-test-delegates-asynchronously-with-kiwi), which I think is the same issue that you had a few months later.