# How to test delegates asynchronously with Kiwi

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ios6, kiwi

H guys,
I have been trying for ages to find some good examples on how to use Kiwi testing to test delegate methods, asynchronously.

I have a manager class that defines the protocols for testing, with a pass and fail method returned in the delegate. Can anyone provide sample code on how to do this? Can I make the test class itself implement the  to call the methods on the manager?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 6):

You can do like in example

```
 SPEC_BEGIN(IFStackOverflowRequestSpec)

describe(@"IFStackOverflowRequestSpec", ^
{
    context(@"question request", ^
    {
        __block IFViewController *controller = nil;

         beforeEach(^
         {
             controller = [IFViewController mock];
         });

        it(@"should conform StackOverflowRequestDelegate protocol", ^
        {
             [[controller should] conformToProtocol:@protocol(StackOverflowRequestDelegate)];
        });

         it(@"should recieve receivedJSON", ^
         {
             NSString *questionsUrlString = @"http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=iphone&pagesize=20";

             IFStackOverflowRequest *request = [[IFStackOverflowRequest alloc] initWithDelegate:controller urlString:questionsUrlString];
             [[request fetchQestions] start];
             [[[controller shouldEventuallyBeforeTimingOutAfter(3)] receive] receivedJSON:any()];
         });

         it(@"should recieve fetchFailedWithError", ^
         {
             NSString *fakeUrl = @"asda";
             IFStackOverflowRequest *request = [[IFStackOverflowRequest alloc] initWithDelegate:controller urlString:fakeUrl];
             [[request fetchQestions] start];
             [[[controller shouldEventuallyBeforeTimingOutAfter(1)] receive] fetchFailedWithError:any()];
         });
    });
});
```

Full example can be founded on [this link.](https://github.com/IgorFedorchuk/use-bdd)

Answer (score 4):

You can do what I *think* you're trying to achieve by creating a mock object that stands in for the delegate, and then checking that the mock object receives the delegate callbacks that you expect.  So the process would look like:

- create a mock object that conforms to the delegate protocol:

`id delegateMock = [KWMock mockForProtocol:@protocol(YourProtocol)];`

- set the mock as the delegate of your manager class:

`[manager setDelegate:delegateMock];`

- create an object containing the data that will be returned by your manager class:

`NSString *response = @"foo";`

- set the assertion that the mock should *eventually* be called with the method and response object (in this case, I'm expecting to receive `managerRepliedWithResponse` and `foo`)

`[[[delegateMock shouldEventually] receive] managerRepliedWithResponse:response];`

- call the method under test:

`[manager performMyMethod];`

The key is setting the expectation *before* you call the method, and using `shouldEventually` which delays the assertion being checked and gives the `manager` object time to perform the method.

There's a range of expectations you can also use that are listed on the Kiwi wiki - https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/wiki/Expectations

I've written the process up [in more detail in a post on my site](http://www.adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/11/testing-asynchronous-network-code-with-kiwi.php), albeit that it's more specifically geared-up to the situation I was dealing with.

Comment: +1 for the very subtle but very important detail! "The key is setting the expectation before you call the method"

Comment: It's been more that a year now and I am struggling with the same thing. It simply doesn't work, before/after with expectFutureValue/without. The only way I can have the damn this wait for the request to be done is by having a real value to check on somewhere.